# filter database with %in% operator

Tags: r

I have a database like this

```
#    col1     col2
#1    5   c('a','b','c')  
#2    3   c('a','b','c','f') 
#3    6   c('a','b','f') 
#4    12  c('a','b','f') 
#5    77  c('b','f') 
#6    3   c('b','f','c')
```

and I want to filter all the rows which 'c' is `%in%` col2 (rows 1,2,6 in the example).
I tried using `filter(data, 'c' %in% col2)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`col2` looks like a list column. For list columns, you need to apply your condition to each element individually. You can accomplish this with `purrr:map_lgl()` or `base::sapply()`. Using `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

filter(data, map_lgl(col2, ~ 'c' %in% .x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  col1 = c(5, 3, 77),
  col2 = c(list(letters[1:3]), list(letters[1:4]), list(c("b", "f")))
)
data
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>    col1 col2     
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     5 <chr [3]>
#> 2     3 <chr [4]>
#> 3    77 <chr [2]>

data %>% filter(col2 %>% map_lgl(~ "c" %in% .x))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>    col1 col2     
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     5 <chr [3]>
#> 2     3 <chr [4]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>